# How to get an Array from "select" field in advanced custom fields

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, advanced-custom-fields

I have a field with cities in ACF, Its a multi-select (ajax enabled ).
So a user can choose different cities (delivery areas in this case).

With this cities i want to populate woocommerce checkout field.
So i need an array with the advanced custom fields selected cities only.

I try to get the object but i get all cities and not the selected ones.
How can i do this?
i tried:

```
$field_name = "acf_cities";
$field = get_field_object($field_name);

echo $field['label'] . ': ' . $field['value'];
$a = get_field_object('field_5a18ee424e883', ['4229'], [false], 
[$load_value]);
print_r($a);
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved.

```
$value = get_field( "field_5a18ee424e883", 4229 );
print_r ($value);
```